# expected ; in the js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have taken the reference from the [dialogflow demo](https://medium.com/@tzahi/how-to-setup-dialogflow-v2-authentication-programmatically-with-node-js-b37fa4815d89). I'm getting error as

> ';' expected.

at the the method `sendTextMessageToDialogFlow`. how can I solve this issue?

Here is my code

```js
router.post('/dialogflow', function(req, res) {
  const projectId = "xxxxxxxxx";

  const LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US';
  let credentials = {
    private_key: xxxxxxxxx,
    client_email: "xxxxxxx",
  }
  let sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials);
  async sendTextMessageToDialogFlow(req.body.query, req.body.id) {
    const sessionPath = this.sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, req.body.id);
    const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          text: req.body.query,
          languageCode: LANGUAGE_CODE
        }
      }
    }
    try {
      let responses = await this.sessionClient.detectIntent(request)
      console.log('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow: Detected intent');
      res.json(responses);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow ERROR:', err);
      cosole.log(err);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: What is throwing that error? What line?

Comment: Why a trailing comma here? `let credentials = {
    private_key: xxxxxxxxx,
    client_email: "xxxxxxx",
  }` Also you can have a ; after the `const request = { ... };`

Comment: Why not. This code is es5 valid.

Comment: @epascarello error is at line `async sendTextMessageToDialogFlow(req.body.query, req.body.id) {`

Comment: See this fiddle for the errors: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lg6f09uw/

Comment: Isn't the keyword `function` missing: `async function sendTextMessageToDialogFlow( ... )`? Or is it valid ES6? It's throwing an error in Firefox.

Comment: @mplungjan by putting the `,` or `;` doesn't make any differ(at that particular position). but still i've removed them &still getting the error

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon after adding the keyword `function` error has gone. I have just copied the code from the link i've provided.

Comment: And I see a missing semicolon at the end of that line..... `}) <------` There is one missing after the let.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be missing the word function and the function params have periods in them
should it look more like:

```
let sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials);
  async function sendTextMessageToDialogFlow(reqBodyQuery, reqBodyId) {
    const sessionPath = this.sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, reqBodyId);
    const request = {
            session: sessionPath,
            queryInput: {
                text: {
                    text: reqBodyQuery,
                    languageCode: LANGUAGE_CODE
                }
            }
    }
    try {
            let responses = await this.sessionClient.detectIntent(request)          
            console.log('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow: Detected intent');
            res.json(responses); 
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.error('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow ERROR:', err);
            cosole.log(err);
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: just put a semicolon at the end of that line

Answer (score 0):

You can't use object properties for parametars of a function. First declare the "query" and "id" variables and then you can use them in the function because they are in the same scope. Also you are missing the function keyword.

```js
router.post('/dialogflow', function(req, res) {
  const projectId = "xxxxxxxxx";

  const LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US';
  let credentials = {
    private_key: xxxxxxxxx,
    client_email: "xxxxxxx",
  }
  let sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials);
  let query = req.body.query;
  let id = req.body.id;

  async function sendTextMessageToDialogFlow() {
    const sessionPath = this.sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, id);
    const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          text: query,
          languageCode: LANGUAGE_CODE
        }
      }
    }
    try {
      let responses = await this.sessionClient.detectIntent(request)
      console.log('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow: Detected intent');
      res.json(responses);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('DialogFlow.sendTextMessageToDialogFlow ERROR:', err);
      cosole.log(err);
    }
  }
});
```